# How do I manupilate a PHP array after getting it from an SQL query?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code :

```php
{...}

$data = $sql->QueryDB("SELECT fdNum AS Num, fdUserNum AS User FROM my_table 
ORDER BY fdNum DESC LIMIT 100;")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);      
echo json_encode($data);
```

I get this array as a result:.

```
[
    {"Num":"195993","User":"345"},
    {"Num":"195992","User":"234"},
    {"Num":"195991","User":"845"}
]
```

But I want to use a function for the User Number(`fdUserNum AS User`) before outputting, it's a simple function called `getUsername()` and simply finds the username given the user number in the array.

So if I am to put the function somewhere in the output array, it'd be here :

```php
[
    {"Num":"195993","User":"getUsername(345)"},
    {"Num":"195992","User":"getUsername(234)"},
    {"Num":"195991","User":"getUsername(845)"}
]
```

But I can't seem to understand how to dissect the array like that and I haven't had luck googling it.

Do you know how is this achievable ?

Comment: What would `getUsername` do? Another query? If so, that is unnecessary. For this purpose, we use `JOIN`s (to get related data from other tables). If it's not another query, then just research array mapping.

Comment: Well. Yes, it does. Because the table is not in the same database but even so I'd still wanna know how to do the question I asked so I can also do normal functions

Comment: Well, in that case, it's array mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Username is also stored in the database, you'd want to do it through a join in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    user.username,
    ...
FROM 
    my_table, user 
WHERE 
    my_table.fdUserNum = user.userNum 
...
```

If you have the username stored in the application itself or in an external service (in that case, be aware that you'll be making 100 requests to that service and would probably be better off by batching the requests), a `getUsername()` function should work fine:

```
foreach ($data as &$row) { 
    $row['User'] = getUsername($row['User']); 
}

unset($row);
```

The `&` makes the row as a reference, allowing you to change the content of the inner array directly. The `unset` after the loop is to make sure you don't accidentally change the last `$row` after the loop.

You can also do it through the index:

```
foreach ($data as $idx => $row) { 
    $data[$idx]['User'] = getUsername($row['User']); 
}
```

You can also use `array_map` by populating the key and returning the resulting array, effectively replacing the old one in the array:

```
function populateUsername($row) {
    $row['User'] = getUsername($row['User']);
}

$data = array_map('populateUsername', $data);
```

Comment: Hey! The joining tables is not possible because the tables are at two different databases, but I tried the second method! It works like a charm! thanks

Comment: @Finneas. In the future I recommend you modify your getUsername function in that case to accept a list of userids, so that you can look them all up in the other database as a single query. You then return the list of users as a `uid => username` map, and look up the uid in the loop instead. Ping me if necessary and I'll update the answer with a better description of how you can do that.